# How to validate the request is coming from the same domain using ASP.Net c# except UrlReferer as this can be faked

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, action-filter

How to validate the request is coming from the same domain using ASP.Net c# except UrlReferer as this can be faked.

I want this validation in Custom Action filter for a specific  API controller.

Comment: You can't: never trust remote clients.

Comment: Anyway, the general-solution is to use some means of protection against request-forgery attacks or unwanted cross-origin requests: (this only works against `POST` requests, of course) and that's to include a cryptographically-random (i.e. unpredictable) string as a hidden _required_ `<input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="123abc" />` which will be HMAC-signed by some private-key. To validate a request you simply check that the `POST`ed `csrfToken` form field was signed by your private-key (and probably include an expiry and any user-session-id info too).

Comment: As @Dai mentioned above you should never trust remote clients nor their URLs instead you should only trust clients based on certificates you issue. This protects your service because the TLS/SSL connection will only be established if the client and server trust each other